# Resource Timing API not showing correct resources in Selenium

Tags: selenium, firefox, geckodriver, resource-timing-api

I have geckodriver latest version installed and I am running latest Firefox version. I wrote a selenium script to just open a URL in firefox and keep the browser open (I am not calling driver.close() or driver.quit())

Here is what the script looks like

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.nrk.no/")
```

The number of resources reported by Resource Timing API is > 100 for this website. 
[image: first Load of nrk.no trhough selenium]

Now, the website is just reloaded again, so that the resources are fetched from cache. 
**NOTE**: I refreshed by just pressing enter in the address bar

The number of resources reported by Resource Timing API is < 40. Same is the discrepancy with the number of resources in Developer Tools in Networks tab. This is happening for every website.

[image: second load of nrk.no]

This is not happening if I just run plain Firefox and refresh the page in the same way. The resources number match always, irrespective of the number of times I refresh the web page.

Comment: I can add screenshots if the description is not good enough

Comment: Can you help us with some captured data and the tools you have used for further analysis? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB I have added screenshots of my issue. Let me know if you need something else

Comment: Tried to get `Resource Timing API` details as per your screenshot. But I am stuck. What I observe from your comment you may be pretty right. So what is your exact Question? Are you stuck any where particularly? How is `Resource Timing` impacting your Automated Test Execution? Thanks

Comment: I am running some tests where I want cached resources. The only way I guess to get cached resources is to reload the page using Selenium and run tests on them. Is there any other way I can cache resources and get away with this bug?

Comment: Yup, you are right. PageFactory can improve the Performance of the Automated Test Execution too. Are you using POM? Thanks

Comment: No. I am just using plain Selenium and not using POM. I just need values from Resource Timing API and run tests on them

Comment: I guess all these properties are Browser properties. You may consider configuring the WebDriver as per your requirement. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @DebanjanB. I will look into it